# .htaccess, mod_rewrite error

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

In an .htaccess file in the root directory, I have the following rules:

```
Options -Indexes  
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$  
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com$1 [R=301]  
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-%]+)/?$ /index.php?m=$1 [L]
```

I have the rules set so that "www" is added to the beginning of every URL entered. The issue is that when I type in "example.com/test" it tries to redirect me to "www.example.comtest" instead of "www.example.com/test". How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com$1 [R=301]
```

on

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301]
```

Comment: Hm, i don't see any other problems but could advice to use logging. So after `RewriteEngine on` place `RewriteLog %PATH/TO/YOUR/LOG/FILE%`, then you can track where appeared problems